# Mule groovy component entry point resolution failure

Tags: groovy, mule, entry-point

I have a very simple Mule (3.x) flow:

```
<spring:bean name="messageHandler" class="mypackage.MessageHandler"/>

<flow name="main">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="in" exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
    <component>         
        <spring-object bean="messageHandler"/>
    </component>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="out"/>
</flow>
```

where `messageHandler` is a simple Groovy class:

```
class MessageHandler {
   String handleMessage(String xml) {   
      return xml + " Received";
   } 
}
```

When I execute the test I get:

> org.mule.model.resolvers.EntryPointNotFoundException: Failed to find entry point for component, the following resolvers tried but failed:[ ... ReflectionEntryPointResolver: Could not find entry point on: "mypackage.MessageHandler" with arguments: "{class java.lang.String}" ... ]

but when I use Java class it works!! (Also works with Callable interface on groovy class).

I'm using gmaven plugin for groovy compling:

```
 <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
      <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <inherited>true</inherited>
      <executions>
         <execution>
              <goals>
                  <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                  <goal>compile</goal>
                  <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                  <goal>testCompile</goal>
               </goals>
          </execution>
      </executions>
   </plugin>
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: I assume MessageHandler is in a package, and it's just that line is missing when you pasted in to this question?

Comment: That's very strange because your Groovy class has the right signature. It would be worth putting a breakpoint in org.mule.model.resolvers.ReflectionEntryPointResolver.invoke() and see why is the handle method not picked up. Until we figure out the issue, you can use http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Entry+Point+Resolver+Configuration+Reference#EntryPointResolverConfigurationReference-Methodentrypointresolver to target handleMessage specifically (no reflection).

Comment: yes of course it is in package.

Comment: I tried:
  '<method-entry-point-resolver>
     <include-entry-point method="handleMessage"/>
  </method-entry-point-resolver>'
but did not help

Comment: If you post your Maven project somewhere and specify the exact Mule version you're using, I could take a deeper look at the issue.

Comment: yes sry, mvn version is: 2.2.1 and groovy version is 1.7.6

Comment: OK but can you share your Maven project somewhere? That way I'll be able to step debug in Mule's code and see what's the root cause of the problem and if there's a way around.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the logger element in the flow before the component to see what's coming into the component.